# How to define the following matrix

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

How to define the following matrix in *Mathematica*?

$$A(n) = 
 \begin{pmatrix}
  B_{1} & B_{2} & \cdots & B_{n} & 1 \\
  B_{n} & B_{1} & \cdots &  B_{n-1} &1 \\
  \vdots  & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots  \\
  B_{2} & B_{3} & \cdots & B_{1} & 1\\
A_{1} & A_{2} & \cdots &  A_{n} &1
 \end{pmatrix}$$

For instance :

for  $n=4$

```
Table[Subscript[B, k], {k, 1, 4}]
```

$$A(4) = 
 \begin{pmatrix}
  B_{1} & B_{2} & B_{3} & B_{4}&1 \\
 B_{4} & B_{1} & B_{2} & B_{3}&1   \\
 B_{3} & B_{4} & B_{1} & B_{2}&1 \\
B_{2} & B_{3} & B_{4} & B_{1}&1  \\
A_{1} & A_{2} & A_{3} & A_{4}&1 
 \end{pmatrix}$$

how to define $A(n)$ as a function of $n$?

And then I wanna manipulate $A(n)$

```
Manipulate[A[n], {n, 2, 30}]
```

Thank you in advance to any one who may be able to give me some ideas

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Three possibilities:

```
With[{n = 4}, 
     ArrayFlatten[{{NestList[RotateRight, Array[B, n], n - 1], 1}, {{Array[A, n]}, 1}}]]

With[{n = 4}, 
     ArrayFlatten[{{ToeplitzMatrix[RotateRight[Reverse[Array[B, n]]], 
                                   Array[B, n]], 1}, {{Array[A, n]}, 1}}]]

With[{n = 4}, 
     PadRight[Append[NestList[RotateRight, Array[B, n], n - 1], Array[A, n]],
              {n + 1, n + 1}, 1]]
```

Comment: +1. But, can you use  `Subscript[B, n] ` $B_{n}$ instead $B[n]$?  `Manipulate[
  ArrayFlatten[{{ToeplitzMatrix[RotateRight[Reverse[Array[B, n]]], 
       Array[B, n]], 1}, {{Array[A, n]}, 1}}] // MatrixForm, {n, 2, 5,
    1}] // TraditionalForm` see [here](http://i.imgur.com/Jq3yDyl.png)

Comment: You can replace `Array[B, n]` with the appropriate call to `Table[]` and `Subscript[]`.